# PowerShell query result list or string

Tags: powershell

My **PowerShell(version 5.1.19041.906)** command `azsphere device-group list --tenant <GUID>` give data as below

Result:

```
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 Id       Name     Descript ProductI OsFeedTy UpdatePo AllowCra CurrentD 
                   ion      d        pe       licy     shDumpsC eploymen 
                                                       ollectio t        
                                                       n                 
 ======================================================================= 
 ba7fab67 Developm Default  556957b4 Retail   Accept o False    None     
 -5cd7-40 ent      developm -aa39-4e          nly syst                   
 1a-9c88-          ent devi 5a-aa4c-          em softw                   
 c4a2e88f          ce group d3208c27          are upda                   
 6932                       7f3c              tes. Don                   
                                              't accep                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 45acb705 Field Te FieldTes 556957b4 Retail   Accept a False    d684d491 
 -a591-4e st       t        -aa39-4e          ll updat          -9229-48 
 41-ba1e-                   5a-aa4c-          es from           4f-a2eb- 
 4b3dd062                   d3208c27          the Azur          fda0168f 
 e1ec                       7f3c              e Sphere          7e27     
                                               Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 07c76f21 Producti Default  556957b4 Retail   Accept a False    None     
 -773e-4e on       producti -aa39-4e          ll updat                   
 0a-ad29-          on devic 5a-aa4c-          es from                    
 569af4eb          e group  d3208c27          the Azur                   
 24a8                       7f3c              e Sphere                   
                                               Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 0e2aed60 Producti Default  556957b4 RetailEv Accept a False    None     
 -41ba-49 on OS Ev Producti -aa39-4e al       ll updat                   
 74-9bfb- aluation on OS Ev 5a-aa4c-          es from                    
 cdee6e1c          aluation d3208c27          the Azur                   
 0fc5               device  7f3c              e Sphere                   
                   group                       Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 8bb2b77c Field Te Default  556957b4 RetailEv Accept a False    None     
 -3839-4b st OS Ev Field Te -aa39-4e al       ll updat                   
 09-b57d- aluation st OS Ev 5a-aa4c-          es from                    
 3f20081c          aluation d3208c27          the Azur                   
 d161               device  7f3c              e Sphere                   
                   group                       Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
```

From the above result, I want to get `ID` where `Description` is equal to `FieldTest`

I tried this command, it wont work, because, result is not in proper list format.

```
((azsphere device-group list --tenant $myTenantId) -split '\n') | Select-String -Pattern 'FieldTest'
```

Also tried doing something like this but no difference

```
((azsphere device-group list --tenant $myTenantId) -split '\n') | select -Skip 1 | Select-Object Id, Name | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

When I use this command, nothing returns. Not sure what is the object returned by the azsphere exe

```
azsphere dev....... | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq 'FieldTest'}
```

[image]

Comment: What object type does `azsphere` returns? I mean prior to splitting on `\n`.

Comment: If `azsphere` was returning PSObjects you could do `(azsphere dev....... | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq 'FieldTest'}).ID`... Do you see an option to have it return a Csv?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I had hoped for the same, something like schedtasks.exe, however it doesn't look like it [AZShere Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/reference/overview?tabs=cliv2beta) .

Comment: Is the table wrapping cells natural output from the application or did you do that for display purposes. If the former it'll make parsing more difficult.

Comment: @Steven the wrapping seems to be a behavior of the PS Host by looking at the docs. It's curious how these guys don't have a compatible PS module.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I definitely agree with the latter, but I don't think it could be PS doing it. Possible the exe itself is sensitive to the console width.  If that is the case it might make things easier if we adjust the console to accommodate the output's natural width, but I can't be certain without trying...

Comment: @Steven you are right exe it self is setting the width of console. But not sure what is the object being returned form that command and (azsphere dev....... | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq 'FieldTest'}).ID doesnt work either.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon how can I identify the type of object being returned from exe?

Comment: It's unlikely an exe is returning objects at all. Which means you'll have to take the output and string parse it into objects. A task made all the more difficult by the wrapping. So, I'm curious if we can get it to stop wrapping possibly by making the console wider.  It would make it much easier.  If not I have some ideas, but I can't code-smith them right now.

Comment: @Steven You're very probably right. In case of, HaBo, can you give us the output of `(azsphere device-group list --tenant <GUID>| Select-Object -first).GetType()` ? I guess the reasonable choice should be to build a wrapper that transforms azsphere output into array/hash of PSObjects. You can also parse the output line by line, but the _objectification_ way should be more adaptable / readable / maintenable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm indeed strange output to parse..
I'm using a Here-String to mimic the file , but in real life you'd probably want to load it from a file.
In that case, make sure you read it as one single, multiline string using the `-Raw` switch:

```
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\azsphereOutput.txt' -Raw
```

If the output is given as an array of strings, combine these into a single multiline string using:

```
$txt = (azsphere device-group list --tenant $myTenantId) -join [environment]::NewLine
```

Next the code:

```
$txt = @"
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 Id       Name     Descript ProductI OsFeedTy UpdatePo AllowCra CurrentD 
                   ion      d        pe       licy     shDumpsC eploymen 
                                                       ollectio t        
                                                       n                 
 ======================================================================= 
 ba7fab67 Developm Default  556957b4 Retail   Accept o False    None     
 -5cd7-40 ent      developm -aa39-4e          nly syst                   
 1a-9c88-          ent devi 5a-aa4c-          em softw                   
 c4a2e88f          ce group d3208c27          are upda                   
 6932                       7f3c              tes. Don                   
                                              't accep                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 45acb705 Field Te FieldTes 556957b4 Retail   Accept a False    d684d491 
 -a591-4e st       t        -aa39-4e          ll updat          -9229-48 
 41-ba1e-                   5a-aa4c-          es from           4f-a2eb- 
 4b3dd062                   d3208c27          the Azur          fda0168f 
 e1ec                       7f3c              e Sphere          7e27     
                                               Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 07c76f21 Producti Default  556957b4 Retail   Accept a False    None     
 -773e-4e on       producti -aa39-4e          ll updat                   
 0a-ad29-          on devic 5a-aa4c-          es from                    
 569af4eb          e group  d3208c27          the Azur                   
 24a8                       7f3c              e Sphere                   
                                               Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 0e2aed60 Producti Default  556957b4 RetailEv Accept a False    None     
 -41ba-49 on OS Ev Producti -aa39-4e al       ll updat                   
 74-9bfb- aluation on OS Ev 5a-aa4c-          es from                    
 cdee6e1c          aluation d3208c27          the Azur                   
 0fc5               device  7f3c              e Sphere                   
                   group                       Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
 8bb2b77c Field Te Default  556957b4 RetailEv Accept a False    None     
 -3839-4b st OS Ev Field Te -aa39-4e al       ll updat                   
 09-b57d- aluation st OS Ev 5a-aa4c-          es from                    
 3f20081c          aluation d3208c27          the Azur                   
 d161               device  7f3c              e Sphere                   
                   group                       Securit                   
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
"@

# create a List object to store the result in (build a CSV really)
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

# split the text on the '=============' line to separate the header block from the data
$hdrBlock, $dataBlock = $txt -split '(?m)^[\s=]+$' -ne ''

# Next proceed by getting the columnwidths. It so happens that in this case all columns 
# have the same width, but you can never be sure of that..
# split the header block in separate lines, remove possible empty or whitespace-only lines
# and remove the single leading and trailing spaces 
$hdrLines   = ($hdrBlock -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }) -replace '^\s|\s$'
$colWidths  = ($hdrLines[0].Trim() -split '\s+') | ForEach-Object { $_.Length + 1 }
$fieldCount = $colWidths.Count
# create a regex string like '^(.{9})(.{9})(.{9})(.{9})(.{9})(.{9})(.{9})(.*)'
$fieldBreaks = '^' + (-join ($colWidths | ForEach-Object { "(.{$_})" })) -replace '\(.{\d}\)$', '(.*)'

# We can now parse the first (headers) block by reassembling the wrapped lines
# start from index 1 here to skip the dashed line above the headers
$lines = for ($i = 1; $i -lt $hdrLines.Count; $i++) {  
    # the unary leading comma ensures $lines will be an array of arrays
    ,($hdrLines[$i] -split $fieldBreaks -ne '')
}
# vertically, join whatever is in the columns as wrapped text
$headers = for ($j = 0; $j -lt $fieldCount; $j++) {
    $column = for ($k = 0; $k -lt $lines.Count; $k++) {
        $lines[$k][$j].Trim()
    }
    # join the wrapped stuff together to form the field content as quoted value
    '"{0}"' -f ($column -join '')
}

# add the completed line to the List
$list.Add($headers -join ',')

# Proceed with the data in $dataBlock
# split each data sub block and loop through
$dataBlock -split '(?m)^[\s-]+$' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
    # split this data block in separate lines, , remove possible empty or whitespace-only lines
    # and remove the single leading and trailing spaces 
    $data = ($_ -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }) -replace '^\s|\s$'
    $lines = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i++) {
        ,($data[$i] -split $fieldBreaks -ne '')
    }
    $row = for ($j = 0; $j -lt $fieldCount; $j++) {
        $column = for ($k = 0; $k -lt $lines.Count; $k++) {
            $lines[$k][$j].Trim()
        }
        # join the wrapped stuff together to form the field content as quoted value
        '"{0}"' -f ($column -join '')
    }
    # add the completed line to the List
    $list.Add($row -join ',')
}

# use ConvertFrom-Csv to convert the CSV we now have in $list into an array of objects
$result = $list | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Display via Out-GridView, because it won't fit the console in table format
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'azsphere Result'

# and/or you could save it as csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\azsphereResult.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Now you can easily filter out the objects you need, like get the ID where Description is equal to FieldTest:

```
($result | Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'FieldTest' }).Id  # --> 45acb705-a591-4e41-ba1e-4b3dd062e1ec
```

Oh yes, nearly forgot.. This is what the result looks like in the GridView:

[image]

Comment: That's a cool parser snippet Worked like a charm!